# Quick search in folder by key press

Tags: macos, mac, finder, search

I switched from PC to Mac, in pc when you're in explorer, you press a key and it highlights the first result of a file/folder that starts with the pressed key,  **and when you press again**  it goes to the next result

In mac, when i press a key in finder or anywhere contains files, it only shows the first result and ignores my repeated key presses that is supposed to move to the next result highlight

how to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way it works in OS X's Finder is you can type a word and the selection will move down as filenames are matched.

The quickest way to move between files, if you aren't in column view, when typing only the first letter, is following up with <kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: Note that this doesn't work when in Columns view.