# MacOS Finder how to go to folders first then files when typing a letter

Tags: keyboard, finder

This is similar to "[Quick search in folder by key press](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86798/quick-search-in-folder-by-key-press)", but with a slightly different case.

When I have a Finder window open and press <kbd>s</kbd> on the keyboard, it selects the first **file** that starts with "s" however I want it to select the first **folder** that starts with "s".

I sort my Finder windows with folders at the top using Finder > Preferences > Advanced > Keep folder on top > checked "In windows when sorting by name".